# Crear URL amigable con variable id=1

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Tengo un archivo llamado colores.php en el cual selecciona de una base de datos los nombres de unos colores y los muestra con un while pasando el color_id de cada uno a una URL para abrir cada color en un fichero llamado color.php.

```
        <?php
                $sql_c=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM colores");

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_c)){
                    $color_id=$row['color_id'];
                    $color=$row['color'];
                    $descripcion=$row['descripcion'];
                    $result = explode('.',$descripcion);

                    echo 
                    '<div class="listado">
                    <hr>
                    <h3><a href="color.php?id='.$color_id.'">' .$color. '</a></h3>
                    <p class="intro">'.$result[0].'.</p>
                </div>';
                }
            ?>
```

Esto hace que se genere un listado con el nombre de cada color y enlazado a cada página propia de cada color: color.php?id=1, color.php?id=2, etc...

El color 1 es el "Negro" y el 2 es el "Blanco". Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer que en las URLs aparezca: `https://miweb.com/color/negro`.

Ahora mismo tengo esto en mi .htaccess

```
#URL Amigable
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Con esto quito las extensiones .php. Así que ahora mismo la página colores se ve en el navegador como `https://miweb.com/colores`, pero cuando hago clic en el color negro aparece `https://miweb.com/color.php?id=1` cuando me gustaría que apareciera `https://miweb.com/color/negro`.

En el archivo color.php lo que hago es recoger el color_id y mostrar la información de ese color, nada más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el error esta en link. Tienes esto ...

```
<h3><a href="color.php?id='.$color_id.'">' .$color. '</a></h3>
```

y debería ser esto...

```
<h3><a href="color/'.$color.'">' .$color. '</a></h3>
```

---

En cuanto a las reglas quizás es mejor usar el id para, aunque se puede hacer por el nombre.

La regla RewriteRule en el .htaccess tendría que ser algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^color/(.*)/(.*)$  color.php?id=$2
```

Esto funcionaria para una URL:

```
www.midominio.com/color/negro/1
```

Si no quieres que aparezca el id en la url, sería...

```
RewriteRule ^color/(.*)$  color.php?name_color=$1
```

Pero luego tendrías que hacer una consulta buscando el id que corresponda al nombre enviado.

---

Ejemplo de **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^color/(.*)/(.*)$  color.php?id_color=$2
```

el **color_lista.php**

```
<?php
                $sql_c=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM colores");

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_c)){
                    $color_id=$row['color_id'];
                    $color=$row['color'];
                    $descripcion=$row['descripcion'];
                    $result = explode('.',$descripcion);

                    echo 
                    '<div class="listado">
                    <hr>
                    <h3><a href="color/'.$color.'/'.$color_id.'">' .$color. '</a></h3>
                    <p class="intro">'.$result[0].'.</p>
                </div>';
                }
            ?>
```

El link debe ser

```
<a href="color/'.$color.'/'.$color_id.'">' .$color. '</a>
```

en **color.php**

```
<?php
$id_color = $_GET['id_color'];
$sql_c=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM colores WHERE color_id=".$id_color." ");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_c)){
echo "<h1>".$row['color']." id= ".$row['color_id']."</h1>";
}

?>
```

---

### Versión sin el id en la URL

Básicamente e slo mismo. Lo que cambia es que la búsqueda se realiza por el nombre, te has de asegurar que no existe ningún nombre repetido. En la base de datos el campo de nombre color debería ser único par evitar problemas.

El **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^color/(.*)$  color.php?name_color=$1
```

El **color_lista.php**

```
<?php
                $sql_c=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM colores");

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_c)){
                    $color_id=$row['color_id'];
                    $color=$row['color'];
                    $descripcion=$row['descripcion'];
                    $result = explode('.',$descripcion);

                    echo 
                    '<div class="listado">
                    <hr>
                    <h3><a href="color/'.$color.'">' .$color. '</a></h3>
                    <p class="intro">'.$result[0].'.</p>
                </div>';
                }
            ?>
```

El **color.php**

```
<?php
$name_color = $_GET['name_color'];
$sql_c=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM colores WHERE color=".$name_color." ");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_c)){
echo "<h1>".$row['color']." id= ".$row['color_id']."</h1>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al hacer eso cambia la URL a misitio.com/color/negro pero no me muestra nada del negro... en el fichero color.php es donde recogía el id del color, pero se ve que ahora no lo recoge... no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: @Jok he ampliado la respuesta con un ejemplo  de los scripts.

Comment: Perfecto!! Ya funciona!! Muchas gracias. La pregunta ahora es... no habría manera de quitar el 1 de la URL? es decir, el `color_id`.

Comment: @Jok si se puede hacer entonces cambiaría la consulta a la base de datos y tendrías que asegurarte de que no existen 2 nombres iguales. Edito la respuesta con esta opción.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no se porqué la segunda forma no me muestra contenido... A parte, el dilema está en que no me gustaría comparar por texto... sino por id... ya que las relaciones de la base de datos las tengo por id... pero no me gusta que se vean los números en la URL.

Comment: De esta última manera, al no funcionarme he hecho un `echo $name_color;` y para mi sorpresa contiene `negro.php/negro`, por eso no puede buscarlo en la base de datos... cuando debería pasar solo el nombre del color `negro`

Comment: Me dio error. pero al cambiar la regla `RewriteRule ^color-name/(.*)$  color.php?name_color=$1` funciona. Al coincidir el nombre **color/** con **color.php** no funciona. cambiando la regla funciona. Eso se puede arreglar o bine cambiando el nombre como he hecho o bine creando una expresión regular más efectiva.