# Cambiar apariencia de la url al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un pequeño codigo que quita una parte del link al cargar la página **'limpia'**, quisiera reemplazar todo el link de la página www.ejemplo.com/... (solo apariencia claro) y se muestre una dirección completa personalizada, pero no sé en que parte de este codigo agregarle para que aparezca el link ya armado.

qué le agrego para que cumpla su  función?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var uri = window.location.toString(); 
if (uri.indexOf("?m=0","?m=0") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?m=0")); 
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es hacer una url amigable. Vas a tener que usar `.htaccess`

Con `.htaccess` puedes diseñar tus propias urls con un aspecto más amigable.

Archivo **.htaccess**

Esta configuración es para un archivo alojado en el http://localhost/carpetas si estuviera en la raíz el rewrite sería así `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /carpeta/
RewriteRule ^mi-url-amigable/(.*)$  index.php?m=$1
```

En tu archivo **index.php** , podrás recoger el valor de la variable `m`...

```
<?php
   echo "<br /> La variable m es : ".$_GET['m'];
 ?>
```

> Ahora para accedera  tu **index.php** deberás poner la siguiente url:
>
> ***www.tu-dominio.com/mi-url-amigable/5***

Puedes configurar las urls como tu necesites con varios parámetros.

Por ejemplo usar nombres de categorías y nombre de un producto:

> www.tu-dominio.com/camisas-verano/hawaiana-color-azul/231

Te paso el link de una pregunta parecida donde se describe con más detalle y de forma práctica el tema de `.htaccess` : [Crear URL amigable con variable id=1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282047/crear-url-amigable-con-variable-id-1/282049#282049)

---

**Observación:**

El cambio no se realiza la cargar la página, sino que tu ya entras con la url "bonita". La url contiene todos los parámetros que necesites.