# Es posible crear una entrada (página) automáticamente al subir los datos a una BBDD?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Por ejemplo si en mi tabla de productos de mysql agrego uno con su respectivo nombre, imagen, ect... quiero que se cree una pagina sobre ese producto automáticamente con una plantilla html/php que ya tenga obviamente.

osea yo puedo agregarle un enlace a mi producto en mysql, que al darle click en su vista previa (en mi home page por ejemplo) me lleve a una pagina con ese enlace . el problema es que eso me va a dar error 404 porque esa pagina no existe. la pregunta es como crearla, para que todos esos productos lleguen a la misma plantilla que este preparada para recibir los datos de distintos productos mediante codigo php y HTML

Eso se puede hacer? si es así como? (no es necesario que me expliques con código).

Comment: El título se presta a la confusión ya que "crear una entrada automáticamente", no corresponde con la explicación. Ya que parece que te refieras a crear una entrada en la BBDD y luego describes:  cuando insertas un nuevo registro en la BBDD es posible mostrar esta nueva entrada en un HTML/PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí que se puede hacer.

Lo explicare con un código sencillo. Luego este código se ha de depurar, como por ejemplo poner la conexión a la base de datos en un archivo separado y usarlo con includes, etc.

El ejemplo es para mostrar la mecánica.

Se crean 2 archivos en uno tendrás el listado con los links de los artículos o productos que quieras ver en detalle, luego se crea una página donde mostrará el detalle del producto.

El segundo archivo recibe un parámetro mediante $_GET por la url donde se le indica el registro que debe mostrar.

Archivo **listado.php**

```
<?php

    // Poner los datos de tu base de datos
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'NAME_USER', 'PASSWORD', 'NAME_BBDD');

    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
    exit();
    }
    $consulta ="SELECT * FROM Articulos ";
    if ($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)) {
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

          echo "<br /> - <a href='ficha_articulo.php?idarticulo=".$fila['idarticulo']."'>".$fila['a_titulo']."</a>";
        }
        $resultado->free();
      }

      /* cerrar la conexión */
      $conexion->close();
 ?>
```

El segundo archivo **ficha_producto.php** donde se recibe el parámetro por la url ($_GET) y busca el registro en concreto, luego lo monta.

```
<?php

  // Poner los datos de tu base de datos
  $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'NAME_USER', 'PASSWORD', 'NAME_BBDD');

  if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
  printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
  exit();
  }


  $consulta ="SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE idarticulo=".$_GET['idarticulo'];
  if ($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)) {
      while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

      echo "<h1>".$fila['a_titulo']."</h1>";
      echo "<p>".$fila['a_contenido']."</p>";
      }
      $resultado->free();
    }

  /* cerrar la conexión */
  $conexion->close();

?>
```

Como es evidente has de crear tu propia consulta con los datos correctos de tu tabla, aquí son un ejemplo.

```
$consulta ="SELECT * FROM Articulos ";
```

y

```
$consulta ="SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE idarticulo=".$_GET['idarticulo'];
```

*Este código se habría de mejorar mucho para temas de seguridad, como control del parámetro recibido. Optimización del código MVC, pero muestra el mecanismo de funcionamiento.*

Comment: Yo entiendo que quiere mostrar un registro de la BBDD en un HTML. Creo que es suficientemente concreto. Le he puesto el código para hacer lo que describe en el desarrollo de la pregunta. Lo que sí es cierto, que el título no se corresponde, o por lo menos no es muy preciso, pero sí que el desarrollo en la descripción se entiende la duda  (concreta) y la que yo he expuesto soluciona la duda. Es posible hacerlo de otras maneras y mejor sí, pero los usuarios pueden aportar nuevas soluciones y tener más respuestas válidas,

Comment: Genio eso era exactamente a lo que me refería!. Sabes que a partir de tu respuesta me surgen otras dudas que ya son mas en materia SEO: ¿esa página que se crea existe realmente para Google?, es decir, las indexa? no es perjudicial que el enlace tenga  `idproducto=`. Y en general.. me recomiendas hacer esto o crear manualmente cada una? Por otra parte Entiendo @Aprendiz que el titulo sea un poco confuso pero créeme que duré rato pensando en una mejor y no tan larga forma de explicarlo y no pude ,así que le di prioridad a la descripción donde creo que si me explico los suficiente

Comment: A nivel de SEo No es recomendable. Google las va a indexar sin probelmas pero no serán muy descriptivas. para que sean descriptivas lo mejor es tratarlas con el archivo .htaccess y que tengan un aspecto similara a `www.miweb.com/camiseta-hombre/1` pero eso es otro tema lo puedes ver en este hilo : [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282047/crear-url-amigable-con-variable-id-1/282049#282049]